# Word or phrase for single letter differing in typeface from the surrounding text

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase for the following phenomenon:

A letter in a text that has a different typeface than the surrounding text for no good reason, such as  the letter *s* in all of the following:

> Engli**s**h Language
>   Engli*s*h Language
>   Englih Language
>   Englih Language

This phenomenon was typical for movable type but also occurrs with other technology, if a special character was not supported by the employed typeface.

Why do I think that such a term might exist? Because the German language has one: *[Zwiebelfisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwiebelfisch_(Buchdruck)).* Unfortunately the translations suggested by dictionaries are not accurate at all:

- [*literal mistake* and *misprint*](http://dict.leo.org/ende/?lp=ende&lang=de&search=zwiebelfisch) – These can also refer to typos and other errors.
- [*printer’s pie*](http://www.dict.cc/?s=zwiebelfisch) – This refers to a total mess of letters occurring when dropping the typecase.

Comment: I think this is ***the*** definition of a *typographical error* because it is, in fact, an error in the typography/typesetting.

Comment: @Jim: It is **a** kind of typographical error, but it’s certainly not the only kind. *Typographical error* would be too broad for me.

Comment: If you had to have a special word for that particular case I think I'd just use ***Zwiebelfisch*** and be prepared to explain it at first use.  My guess is that even if there were an English word that meant the same thing, you'd have to explain that too.

Comment: A quick Google search seems to show that, for the general German public, _Zwiebelfisch_ can, indeed, be used to describe a simple typo.

Comment: @TimWard: I do not what exactly you found, but be careful on interpreting Google searches of that word. *Zwiebelfisch* is also the name of a popular newspaper column on the German language. I strongly doubt that most Germans will be aware of that name’s origin or use it to refer to a typo.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft : This was based on pictures that show what I would have called a typo, which people had commented in German using the word 'Zwiebelfisch'. :)

Comment: @TimWard: That’s probably because it was from said language column or somebody suggested to submit it to that column or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [some debate](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/out-of-sorts.html) about where the English phrase "out of sorts" comes from; since the individual characters of a typeface were called a "sort", it's feasible that ["out of sorts" originally meant to run out of a needed "sort" for typesetting](http://www.environmentalhistory.org/revcomm/features/life-in-a-print-shop/). A common method of dealing with that would be to employ a different "sort" in a different typeface - which would look like your zwiebelfisch.

It's not likely that anyone will know what you mean using that phrase though, as it basically means "not orderly" at this point. Since we no longer deal with manual typesetting, we'd probably just call it a "missing glyph" or "wrong font" at this point.

Thinking about this a bit more, I think "[odd sort](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sort)" is likely the closest English translation. It describes a member of a set (a sort) that is unlike the others (odd). A common expression would be eg., "he's an odd sort of fellow" meaning he's different than your average person. Given "sort" history with typesetting, it's possible (though I have no references) that it originally described the exact scenario zwiebelfisch does. Though it has mostly lost any historical connection (if it, indeed, ever had any) it would still adequately describe a character printed differently than others around it.

"[Odd fish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/odd%20fish)" is another English term that *may* have some historical connection. An "odd fish" is a name for something that's of an "odd sort" (eg., he's an odd fish) and it would seem to share the same "fish" connection with zwiebelfisch. I'm not aware of English ever using "fish" as typesetting slang, but serif in Japanese is [uroko - fish scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) so perhaps there is a connection there.